# Change the text of a Label inside a LoginView

Tags: .net, asp.net, loginview

```
<asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" />,
            You're <asp:Label ID="AgeLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"> </asp:Label></span>!
        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

I want to do something like

```
AgeLabel.Text = Profile.GetPropertyValue("Age").ToString();
```

How can I do this? AgeLabel i inside a template so it looks like I can't refference it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried following?

```
<asp:Label ID="AgeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Profile.GetPropertyValue("Age").ToString() %>' />
```

Otherwise you could access the Label from Codebehind with FindControl:

```
Dim AgeLabel As Label = DirectCast(HeadLoginView.FindControl("AgeLabel"), Label)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can break elements apart, there is an option "Convert to template" for login control. You will have all elements as separate elements but the functionality of Login control is preserved